# How Can I write to a file the duplicates I dropped in a Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

input:

```
Col1    Col2
1       apple
2       apple
3       orange
4       grape
5       grape
6       grape
```

Here is what I am running to drop the duplicates.

```
#Drop Duplicates if any keep first
sortfile1.drop_duplicates(['Col2'],keep = 'first', inplace = True)
```

Now my dataframe looks like this... Which is correct.

Output:

```
 Col1    Col2
1       apple
3       orange
4       grape
```

Here is the issue.. I need to show the records I removed from the dataframe.

So i need to also have an output file that shows the records I removed.

Output File Wanted:   (I need to have a csv file with records I removed, like this)

```
Col1    Col2
2       apple
5       grape
6       grape
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you should using `duplicated`

```
df[df.Col2.duplicated()]
Out[396]: 
   Col1   Col2
1     2  apple
4     5  grape
5     6  grape
```

Comment: I tried that... I have the Exact code you have it gives me back this   (all records                                                                                                           Col1    Col2
    1       apple
    2       apple
    3       orange
    4       grape
    5       grape
    6       grape

Comment: @Danny you need to assign it back like df1=df[df.Col2.duplicated()] and print(df1)

Comment: Thanks That worked!!!                                                                                        Duplicated = df[df.Col2.duplicated()]

Answer (score 0):

The anwer given by @W-B is suffice , you just need to save it to csv.

```
>>> df
   Col1    Col2
0     1   apple
1     2   apple
2     3  orange
3     4   grape
4     5   grape
5     6   grape

>>> df1 = df[df.Col2.duplicated()]

>>> df1
   Col1   Col2
1     2  apple
4     5  grape
5     6  grape
```

saving dataframe to a csv file:

By default it will keep the record comma separated.

```
df1.to_csv('example.csv')
```

In case you want the records to be whitespace delimited the use `sep=' '` .

```
df1.to_csv('example.csv', sep=' ')
```

OR , delimit by a tab

```
 df1.to_csv('example.csv', sep='\t')
```